# Export data from Access 2010 to Excel 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

i am exporting data from Access to Excel using recordset to transfer data from access query to excel(as I have to manual formatting which cannot be done with transferSpreadsheet) and while i am using the code

```
with sheet1
.range("A2").CopyRecordset rs1
End With
```

This works fine till 3 sheets but when I initiate 4th sheet (as Excel has 3 sheets by default)

```
Set sheet4 = wb.Worksheets.Add
```

I am getting an error saying

> Subscript out of range error.

Can someone help me out with the same?

Answer (score 0):

Which line errors - adding the worksheet?

Code works for me:

Set Sheet4 = Sheets.Add

Maybe post your full procedure for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's impossible to say for sure.  Maybe a worksheet name is misspelled.  Just a guess.  Try the code samples below for some different ways of how to do this kind of task.

```
'************* Code Start *****************
'This code was originally written by Dev Ashish
'It is not to be altered or distributed,
'except as part of an application.
'You are free to use it in any application,
'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
'
'Code Courtesy of
'Dev Ashish
'
Sub sCopyFromRS()
'Send records to the first
'sheet in a new workbook
'
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim intMaxCol As Integer
Dim intMaxRow As Integer
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Dim objWkb As Workbook
Dim objSht As Worksheet
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Customers", _
                    dbOpenSnapshot)
  intMaxCol = rs.Fields.Count
  If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveLast:    rs.MoveFirst
    intMaxRow = rs.RecordCount
    Set objXL = New Excel.Application
    With objXL
      .Visible = True
      Set objWkb = .Workbooks.Add
      Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets(1)
      With objSht
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(intMaxRow, _
            intMaxCol)).CopyFromRecordset rs
      End With
    End With
  End If
End Sub

Sub sCopyRSExample()
'Copy records to first 20000 rows
'in an existing Excel Workbook and worksheet
'
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Dim objWkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim intLastCol As Integer
Const conMAX_ROWS = 20000
Const conSHT_NAME = "SomeSheet"
Const conWKB_NAME = "J:\temp\book1.xls"
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set objXL = New Excel.Application
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Customers", dbOpenSnapshot)
  With objXL
    .Visible = True
    Set objWkb = .Workbooks.Open(conWKB_NAME)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets(conSHT_NAME)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
      Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets.Add
      objSht.Name = conSHT_NAME
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    intLastCol = objSht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    With objSht
      .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(conMAX_ROWS, _
          intLastCol)).ClearContents
      .Range(.Cells(1, 1), _
        .Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
      .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
  End With
  Set objSht = Nothing
  Set objWkb = Nothing
  Set objXL = Nothing
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub

Sub sCopyRSToNamedRange()
'Copy records to a named range
'on an existing worksheet on a
'workbook
'
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Dim objWkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Const conMAX_ROWS = 20000
Const conSHT_NAME = "SomeSheet"
Const conWKB_NAME = "c:\temp\book1.xls"
Const conRANGE = "RangeForRS"

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set objXL = New Excel.Application
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Customers", dbOpenSnapshot)
  With objXL
    .Visible = True
    Set objWkb = .Workbooks.Open(conWKB_NAME)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets(conSHT_NAME)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
      Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets.Add
      objSht.Name = conSHT_NAME
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    objSht.Range(conRANGE).CopyFromRecordset rs
  End With
  Set objSht = Nothing
  Set objWkb = Nothing
  Set objXL = Nothing
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
'************* Code End *****************
```